# Angular 4: Custom style for ngbdatepicker select year dropdown

Tags: angular, ngb-datepicker

I'm using ngbDatepicker in my angular application.

```
<div class="form-group  mb-0 mr-5 ">
              <label class="form-control-label">Event Date</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Select Event Date" [minDate]="{year: 1900, month: 1, day: 1}"
                       name="dp" formControlName="eventDate" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" (select)="selected($evet)">
                <div class="input-group-append border-0">
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button"></button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

This works fine but my Select Year dropdown is way too long to accommodate a lot of years. I am trying to apply scroll to this dropdown but not able to access this element.

[image]

Have tried to access ** ngbDatepicker** reference, but cannot seem to get the reference to this select element?

```
@ViewChild('d') ndbDate: any
```

Is there a better way to go about it? Suggestions are welcome :)